# Symfony Sonata admin languages not work

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I install Sonata admin Bundle, everything work but I don't have any language - buttons and text in admin is like before translated example :

label.select_context  , btn_filter  (not filter but btn_filter)

and other - where I can setup language to sonata admin ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enable **translator** in config.yml.

like.

```
    framework:
       translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sonata admin uses the language set in the configuration file. But that's not your problem, the problem is that the cache doesn't include the sonata admin translation files.

Clearing the cache will fix your problems:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: I do php app/console cache:clear and still have  link_action_create and this type of labels for buttons

Comment: I had already run the cache:clear command but I needed to run it a second time to get it working, no idea why